# C# Enacting Method After Browser Control Finishes Loading?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

So, I was getting a null reference on the browser control's document after sending to a Url. I assumed it was because the document wasn't finished loading. So I added an event handler:

```
    string[] m_ArgCache = null;
    internal void AutomateThreadCreation(string title, string content)
    {
        SendToNewThreadByIndex();

        m_ArgCache = new string[] { title, content };
        Browser.DocumentCompleted += Browser_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    void Browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(m_ArgCache != null)
            AttemptPost(m_ArgCache[0], m_ArgCache[1]);
    }
```

However,I'm still getting a null error:

[image]

Would anyone be willing to tell me how to go about this?

Edit:

I should also add that this method works properly if I'm already on the page. The issue comes when I navigate to the page and then try the method.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create an event handler for Browser.Validated instead of DocumentCompleted.

```
    string[] m_ArgCache = null;
    internal void AutomateThreadCreation(string title, string content)
    {
        SendToNewThreadByIndex();

        m_ArgCache = new string[] { title, content };
        Browser.Validated += Browser_Validated;
    }

    void Browser_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_ArgCache != null)
            AttemptPost(m_ArgCache[0], m_ArgCache[1]);
    }
```